# Add JLabel with image to JList to show all the images

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Here is my code.  It does not show images in the frame and instead shows some text. would anybody please suggest me that what change I should make in the code so that it allows me to show the images in a frame?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ListView {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    JLabel lbl[] = new JLabel[10];
    DefaultListModel listModel;
     ImageIcon[] b = new   ImageIcon[10];
    //JList lsm=new JList();
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
     File folder = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures");
     File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
      JLabel[] lb=new JLabel[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
    {
          System.out.println("chek panth"+listOfFiles[i].getName().toString());
  //      b[i] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/" + listOfFiles[i].getName().toString()));
         b[i] = new ImageIcon("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/" + listOfFiles[i].getName().toString());
         lb[i]=new JLabel(b[i]);
         listModel.add(i, lb[i]);

    }
    JList lsm=new JList(listModel);

    Component add = frame.add(new JScrollPane(lsm));

    frame.setVisible(true);

}


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that I would not design the code this way, but I wanted to keep it as close to the original as practical, while making it work to display a list of images on a Windows based box.

[image: ListView]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ListView {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/" +
            "My Pictures/Sample Pictures";
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("check path"+listOfFiles[i]);
            String name = listOfFiles[i].toString();
            // load only JPEGs
            if ( name.endsWith("jpg") ) {
                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(listOfFiles[i]));
                listModel.add(count++, ii);
            }
        }
        JList lsm=new JList(listModel);
        lsm.setVisibleRowCount(1);

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(lsm));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use listcellrenderer to display both image and text in jlist probably like the one below for showing label with icon in list

```
 public class myRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) 
    {
        //JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if(value instanceof JLabel)
        {
            this.setText(((JLabel)value).getText());
            this.setIcon(((JLabel)value).getIcon());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful :-) Just: a) you rarely (as in never-ever) have components in a ListModel b) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: thats right,but my friend was having trouble adding jlabel with icon to the list so i have to find the solution somehow