# How to display multiple column in a JTree

Tags: java, swing

How can we display multiple fields of a object in DefaultTreeCellRenderer. Please let me know if there is any tutorial. I have tried [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) but it isn't talked about displaying the object data in many column.

Comment: JTrees display one column.  JTables display more than one column.  You can have a popup display the rest of the information for a JTree column.

Comment: The `DefaultMutableTreeNode` just uses the `toString()` method of the `Object` passed into its contructor, so you could extract the fields there. Alternatively, there are such things as `TreeTable`s, but not in the JDK so you'd have to find one.

Comment: @kuporfic I have tried that method but I am not able to put some space between the two column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`, mentioned [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258638/230513). The stand-alone JAR is in the NetBeans distribution:

> `NetBeans/platform/modules/org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After some research I have found the tutorial which I was looking. Here is the link

http://www.hameister.org/JavaSwingTreeTable.html

Comment: What in this lengthy, German-language article did you find sufficiently helpful to warrant a link-only answer?

Comment: @trashgod I used google translate to change it to english and I could not find any other answer. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: I like Outline view but isn't it netbean specific ?

Comment: No, it's stand-alone; the JAR is in the NetBeans distribution.

Comment: On closer examination, I see an informative class diagram in the linked article.