# java.lang.AssertionError while running swing outline view using Java web start

Tags: java, swing, outline-view

I have implemented the [Outline view](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component) for my JTable Tree view mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841183/access-tree-object-in-netbeans-outline/2841582#2841582) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405702/how-to-display-multiple-column-in-a-jtree). The implementation is successfully running in eclipse workspace but when I ran the application using Java Web Start. I faced the following issue.

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: Do resetting of permutation only in AWT queue!
    at org.netbeans.swing.etable.ETable.resetPermutation(ETable.java:1380)
    at org.netbeans.swing.etable.ETable.tableChanged(ETable.java:1268)
    at org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline.tableChanged(Outline.java:943)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3698)
    at org.netbeans.swing.etable.ETable.setModel(ETable.java:861)
    at org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline.setModel(Outline.java:636)
    at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:644)
    at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(JTable.java:572)
    at org.netbeans.swing.etable.ETable.<init>(ETable.java:287)
    at org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline.<init>(Outline.java:226)
```

Could you please advice me what could be the reason behind it.

Comment: are assertions disabled in eclipse and enabled outside?

Comment: @vishal_aim I am not sure how to check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by disabling the assertion from the java web start. Modification in JNLP files are

added `java-vm-args="-da"` in the jnlp file as

```
<java  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.7+"  java-vm-args="-da" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m" />
```

Thanks @vishal_aim for the hints