# How to expand the rows in the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

File Explorer Image:

[image]

I was making a file explorer in Java and in the given image I manage to generate the output a `JTree` on the left side, which expands and collapses, and a `JTable` on the right side.

But as we experience in the Windows Explorer, if we click any folder in the table it expands and shows its contents. In my file explorer, how can I implement it--> If I click the row and if it is a directory/folder then it would expand and shows its contents?

Comment: See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for an example to work from.

Comment: I viewed that example. But in that example, when I want to expand a folder from the table, I have to click it and from the bottom, I have to click "open", which opens the folder in the default file explorer of the system.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `MouseListener` to the `JTable`?

Comment: See also `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline` illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16410632/230513).