# A Table like JTreeTable with editable components like ComboBox, TextArea, CheckBox as Rows

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jxtreetable, jtreetable

[image]

Is there any custom plugin(like JTreeTable with editable java components) in java, like in the above image.

I know this can be done by Extending JTreeTable or JXTreeTable Class or using TreeCellEditor etcetera...  But, I need a quite exact structure like shown in the above image, Please guide me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say.  JTreeTable is not part of the core API, so there a many different implementations out there. One can be found here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JTreeTablecomponent.htm . Which one are you using?

Comment: I have not yet decided to use anything, I am waiting for a treetable with above structure (shown in the image) in JAVA. Once I got a Structure like that in JAVA, then I will start implementation.

Comment: Also, I am not specifically talking about JTreeTable or JXTreeTable here, I need anything in java with that structure.

Comment: click to jxtreetable and jtreetable too for more info

Answer (score 6):

[`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258638/230513), uses the same [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) schema as `JTable`. For example, to get a column of checkboxes, your `RowModel` implementation of `getColumnClass()` should return `Boolean.class` and your implementation of `isCellEditable()` should return `true` for the `Logical2` column. I haven't tried it, but `DefaultCellEditor`, instantiated with  a `JCheckBox`, should work for the combo column.

[image]