# Jtree with checkboxes and JTextfields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtree

I've been trying to figure out how to have a JTree with both checkboxex and JTextFields. I only found examples with checkboxes but I would like the ability to add nodes with a textfield instead where the user can input a string. Closets I came was a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852193/jtextfield-in-jtree-make-it-editable) Anybody that can help me with that?

Comment: *"Anybody that can help me with that?"* If you mean "can anyone turn that example into exactly what I need?" the answer is "probably, but we won't - this is a Q&A site, not a help desk". What effort have you put into the task? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: M.Dani The link you shared in your post does includes textfields..

Comment: @user3437460, Yes I know that, however it seems it have some problems when trying to edit. And I'm trying to figure out how to correct that issue.

Comment: @M.Dani Perhaps you can show what you have tried and the problems you faced.

Comment: See also [*A Table like JTreeTable with editable components like ComboBox, TextArea, CheckBox as Rows*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530463/230513).