# Method valueForPathChanged in TreeModel interface (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

I am implementing [`TreeModel` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) and have implemented all methods except for the `valueForPathChanged`.

In my case, the values are not going to be programatically changed.

Why TreeModel interface contains this method? Is it used by `JTree` in any circumstances, or I am safe to leave it unimplemented?

Code for the reference, it works. I am just concerned whether `valueForPathChanged` is required by the JTree:

```
class ParamsTreeModel implements TreeModel  {
    private final TreeRoot root;
    private final List<TreeModelListener> listeners = new ArrayList<TreeModelListener>();
    ParamsTreeModel(TreeRoot root)  {
        this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if(parent instanceof Param) return null;
        if(structuredMap.containsKey(parent))   {
            return structuredMap.get(parent).get(index);
        }
        // Root
        return partNames.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if(parent instanceof Param) return 0;
        if(parent instanceof TreeRoot)  return partNames.size();
        return structuredMap.get(parent).size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        if(parent instanceof TreeRoot)  return partNames.indexOf(child);
        return structuredMap.get(parent).indexOf(child);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return (node instanceof Param);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are required to implement the [`valueForPathChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-java.lang.Object-) method, as defined in the [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) interface, you are free to leave it empty. [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258638/230513), is an example. The [`valueForPathChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html#valueForPathChanged-javax.swing.tree.TreePath-java.lang.Object-) method is typically used to support cell editing. As a concrete example, the implementation in [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html), seen [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.java), "sets the user object of the `TreeNode` identified by `path` and posts a node changed [event]."