# How to put jpg in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, imageicon, listcellrenderer

this is an example of what I wrote so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class program {

    JFrame win = new JFrame("bla bla");

    final private String[] animals = { "dog", "cat", "mouse" };

    private void Start() {
        JPanel superior = new JPanel();
        superior.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        win.getContentPane().add(superior, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        final JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(animals);
        ((JLabel) comboBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        superior.add(comboBox);
        win.setSize(440, 290);
        win.setResizable(false);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        program window = new program();
        window.Start();
    }
}
```

I've a single jpg for each item of *animals* String array in a folder called *jpg* placed on the same level of *(default package)*. I'm using eclipse.

My idea was to make a JComboBox able to display **only** jpgs, while using strings with certain mouse click events I've already coded (but not reported just to make it short).

I've read [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomComboBoxwithImage.htm), [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) and [this](http://mdsaputra.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/imageicon-in-jcombobox-java/), but I can't really get the job done :(

Could anyone explain me how to get what I want, maybe modifying my code so I can study it?

Comment: Please have a look at, how to [add images to Eclipse Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230), for more information on the use of the same, visit this [Load ImageIcon Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and the last link in this link will provide the usage of the same thingy explained in link 1. One more [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230), though not related, but sufficient enough to give an idea. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544652/418556) for tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to supply a custom `ListCellRenderer` to the combobox which is capable of displaying an image (and other information as you need)

See [Providing a custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more details

You can load a image using the [`ImageIO` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html). You may need to wrap the result in a `ImageIcon` in order to render it more easily, but that will depend on you API implementation

I would recommend using a [`DefaultListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) as it extends from `JLabel` and will make you life easier

**Really simple example**

I don't have enough information to form a fully runnable example, but essentially, the values added to the combo box model should, in some way, contain a reference to the image you want to load.

This way, when required, you can extract the image and display it using the cell renderer...

```
public class ImageCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof ??) {
            ImageIcon icon = ...;
            setIcon(icon);
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

And apply the renderer...

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
cb.setRenderer(new ImageCellRenderer());
```

**Updated**

Now assuming that the images are named `[animal].jpg` (so `dog` would be `dog.jpg`) you should be able to build a simple `Map`, mapping the name to the animal image...

```
// List of animals...
final private String[] animals = { "dog", "cat", "mouse" };

/*...*/

// Map of animal icons...
Map<String, Icon> mapImages = new HashMap<>();
// Build the icon image mapping
for (String animal : animals) {
    mapImages.put(animal, new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/" + animal + ".jpg))))
}

// Create a new cell renderer, passing the mappings
ImageCellRenderer renderer = new ImageCellRenderer(mapImages);

// Create a new combo box
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(animals);
// Apply the renderer
comboBox.setRenderer(renderer);

/*...*/

public class ImageCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    // Icon mappings
    private Map<String, Icon> mapImages

    public ImageCellRenderer(Map<String, Icon> mapImages) {
        // Make a new reference to the icon mappings
        this.mapImages = new HashMap<>(mapImages);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof String) {
            // Look up the icon associated with the animal...
            Icon icon = mapImages.get(value.toString());
            setIcon(icon);
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already read the first link, I'm reading the second and the third. I'm asking too much If I pray you to write down some code as example...? Sorry if yes, and thanks anyway for the info!

Comment: Sorry, can't understand it... what argument should I use for the if? Where should I place my String array? How to link an icon to a string?

Comment: Wow!!! We're almost there! What I get in the combobox list now is the jpg on the left and the string name on the right. There's a way to display only jpgs? And if yes, will I be able to use setSelectedItem(animals[i]) and getSelectedItem(animals[i]) methods for some mouse click actions related to items in the animals string array? If I need to post the code I will, meanwhile thanks a lot!

Comment: In the cell render, after calling super.getListCellRendererComponent, call setText(null). And yes, you should be able to call get/setSelectedItem and get/set the a String value

Comment: Yep it works! Just saying thanks for your patience, learning a bunch of stuff from this! :)